# 2-in-3-SAT vs. Gaussian elimination

Tags: np-complete, gaussian-elimination, open-problem

$\mathsf{P}\stackrel{?}{=}\mathsf{NP}$ is an open question currently. However monotone 2-in-3-SAT is an $\mathsf{NP}$-complete problem.

Further any 2-in-3 clause $(x\lor y\lor z)$ can be reduced to a modular equation $x+y+z\equiv 2 \pmod 3$. Then we can convert any problem in $\mathsf{NP}$ to a system of such formulas.

If it's possible to use Gaussian elimination (and why it should be impossible?) then it is possible to solve this in polynomial time which implies $\mathsf{P=NP}$.

But this was so simple, so trivial, that I don't even believe that this is possible and I'm correct. On the other hand simplicity of this doesn't allow me to see that something is wrong.

So, is there something I am missing or this really is so simple?

Comment: I was not aware that Gaussian Elimination can be applied to modular arithmetic. In fact, I never heard of anyone defining real numbers or continuity in that context

Comment: $2$ in $3$ is not $x \vee y \vee z$.

Comment: @gt6989b, XOR-SAT is solved by Gaussian elimination.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, in fact that just means that for clause $(x\lor y\lor z)$ I only can choose either $xy\overline z$, $x\overline yz$ or $\overline xyz$.

Comment: "Exactly $2$ in $3$"  is indeed $x +  y + z \equiv 2 \mod 3$, but you said "monotone": to be monotone, the clause would have to be "at least $2$ in $3$".

Comment: @RobertIsrael, monotone in this context means that formula has only positive or negative literals. E.g. if formula has clause $(x\lor y\lor\overline z)$ the formula is not monotone.

Comment: How do you handle the restriction $x \in \{0,1\}$ if you're doing arithmetic mod $3$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael, aren't values in the matrix A always 0-1 in the end of algorithm? Only left part of vector b is allowed to have values greater than 1. However, I'm not good with Gaussian elimination and that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Gaussian elimination mod $3$ uses arithmetic in the integers mod $3$, where values can be $0$, $1$ or $2$.  It is likely to give you solutions where some of the variables have value $2$, and these do not correspond to solutions of the $2$-in-$3$-SAT problem.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, okay, can I use Gaussian elimination to solve system of equations with different modulo? E.g. adding there $x+y+z\equiv 0\pmod 2$.

Comment: How are you going to do Gaussian elimination when the variables on the left hand side and the constants on the right hand side aren't constrained by the same modulus, mod 2 on one side and mod 3 on the other?

Comment: @KyleJones, is there also a restriction for Gaussian elimination that every equation must be constrained by the same modulus?

Comment: @rus9384 Yes.  It will give nonsensical results otherwise.  I think the actual constraint is that everything be under the same modulus and the modulus must be prime.

Comment: @KyleJones, this answers the question "why should it be impossible?"